# Differential Equations - Crossing a River

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I am an independently studying student, and I am trying to solve the question in the attached [link.](http://www.cengage.com/math/book_content/0495108243_zill/projects_archive/de8e/Project3.pdf)

Essentially, I need help solving Equation (3) in the below attached picture for the ratio $v_r/v_s$. I do not understand how to separate the variables to create an equation that I can integrate each side. Also, I do not know how I would use my initial condition that $y(w) = 0$.

I have reproduced the necessary equations here:

> Using the fact that $dx/dt$ is the component of $\vec{v}$ in the $x$-direction and $dy/dt$ is the component of $\vec{v}$ in the $y$-direction we see from Figure 2(b) that 
>   \begin{align} 
> \newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left|#1\right|}
> \renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
> \begin{split}
>  \vec{v} = \left( \frac{dx}{dt}, \frac{dy}{dt} \right) 
>         &= \vec{v}_s + \vec{v}_r = (-v_s \cos \theta, -v_s \sin \theta) + (0, v_r) \\ 
>         &= (-v_s \cos \theta, v_r - v_s \sin \theta),
> \end{split} \tag{1}
> \end{align}
>   where the magnitude $\abs{\vec{v}_r} = v_r$ and $\abs{\vec{v}_s} = v_s$ are speeds. By using the fact that the corresponding components in (1) the above equation are equal and that $\cos \theta = x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $\sin \theta = y/ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ we 've constructed the system of first-order differential equations
>   \begin{align} 
> \begin{split}
> \frac{dx}{dt} &= - v_s \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\
> \frac{dy}{dt} &= v_r - v_s \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.
> \end{split} \tag{2}
> \end{align}
>   Because $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$, the solution curves of this system of differential equations satisfy the single first-order equation
>   $$ \tag{3}
> \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-(v_r/v_s)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x}.
> $$

Edit: Thank you for the help with formatting!

Comment: This is a homogeneous ODE. Use substitution $y(x) = w(x) \cdot x $ and it'll be reduced to separable equation.